# ngrx effect - waiting on external data

Tags: asynchronous, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I have an effect which runs when a user is downloaded and stored in state:

```js
getMetadata$ = createEffect(() => {
  return this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(fromUserSelectors.getUserSuccess),
    concatLatestFrom(() => this.store.select(fromProductSelectors.selectProduct)),
    exhaustMap(([user, product]) =>
      // do something with user and product
    )
  );
});
```

This effect is triggered when `getUserSuccess` is dispatched.

However, you can see on the 4th line, I also need the product which is stored in a different store and is downloaded asynchronously to the user being downloaded. So it isn't necessarily populated until later.

How can I tell this effect to wait for the product to be populated before resuming? I do not want to retrigger the effect. I thought that was the purpose of `concatLatestFrom` introduced in ngrx v12, but maybe I am misunderstanding it.

I am aware I could have multiple actions being listened to in my `ofType` call and listen to `fromProductSelectors.getProductSuccess`, but I only want this effect to run when `getUserSuccess` is called, not `fromProductSelectors.getProductSuccess` too, but need the `selectProduct` to not be undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `filter` operator to wait until it becomes available.

```
getMetadata$ = createEffect(() => {
  return this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(fromUserSelectors.getUserSuccess),
    concatLatestFrom(() => this.store.select(fromProductSelectors.selectProduct).pipe(filter(x => !!x)),
    exhaustMap(([user, product]) =>
      // do something with user and product
    )
  );
});
```

Comment: Hey @timdeschryver - thanks for the answer. 

However, the filter seems to kill the stream early. I can see the selector from `selectProduct` is populated later, but this stream never seems to resume. And as a result, the `exhaustMap` is never reached.